# Unistalled C++ Redistributables on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, visual-c++

Windows Vista Service Pack2
32 bit

I uninstalled C++ re-distrubutables (was not aware they are necessary for some applications to run) and I am facing error `Cannot start application because the side-by-side configuration is not correct` when i start applications like Avast, Revo Uninstaller etc. 
I came across [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/different-versions-and-updates-of-microsoft-visual/d966bde7-4396-4d14-ab3d-04f0924a99f6) page. But the downloaded `vcredist_86.exe` doesn't seem to do much. It extracts itself and that's it nothing after that. No error nothing.

I just finished installing 300+ MB updates on my system, so i don't want to use the System Restore option [And, I don't know which Restore Point to revert to]. Any other way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the [Command prompt (cmd.exe) with admin rights](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run this command:

```
SxsTrace Trace -logfile:SxsTrace.etl
```

Now run the program which causes the SideBySide error.

Go back to the command prompt press `ENTER` to generate the `SxsTrace.etl`. Now type this:

```
sxstrace Parse -logfile:SxSTrace.etl -outfile:SxSTrace.txt
```

Now open the `SxSTrace.txt` trace and look which VC++ runtime is missing.

```
8.0.50727.42 = Visual C++ 2005 RTM
8.0.50727.762 = Visual C++ 2005 Sp1
9.0.21022.8 = Visual C++ 2008 RTM
9.0.30729.1 = Visual C++ 2008 Sp1
```

After figuring out which version is missing, download the Runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Determine which VC++ redistributable(s) you need (look at the Event logs related to the Side-By-Side errors to determine versions-- v8 is 2005, v9 is 2008, v10 is 2010, v11 is 2012).

Download the one that matches the program’s architecture (32- or 64-bit) from Microsoft, and install them.

Links:

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package (x86 and x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package (x86 and x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86 and x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86 and x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86 and x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347)

Comment: (-1) because VC++ 2010 and 2012 don't use WinSxS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSxS)

Comment: @magicandre1981 - How is the fact VC++ 2010 and 2012 not using WinSxS the fault of the author?  The general advice is sound install the required redistributable package used by the software in question.

Comment: @Ramhound side by side errors can only occur for VC++ version which can installed side by side. So 2010 and VS2012 links are useless. If such runtime is missing you simply get the message that msvcr110.dll is missing (VC++ 2012). Next he also posted links to an Security fix. If the tool requires the RTM version, you get the side by side error. So running sxstrace is the **ONLY** way to see which Runtime is missing.

Comment: @magicandre1981 not true, you can see with procexp for example that applications use the newest update for the runtime available