# some programs running much slower after mscvrt runtime redistributable delete/reinstall

Tags: windows-7, performance, dll, runtime

**UPDATE**: It appears that there may have been an unfortunate coincidence. It seems that right around the time I was doing these builds and deletions of redistributables, my laptop power adapter was quietly dying and my DELL E6410 was quietly throttling the CPU in reaction to that. Will post more if that turns out not to be the issue, but a new power adapter is making this faster so far...

---

I'm running Windows 7 on a Dell Latitude E6410 laptop.

Background: I need to compile a program using cl from the command line and it was failing with an error about winsock2. A page I read said I should reinstall Windows SDK. That install was failing and other page said it was sometimes necessary to uninstall mscv runtime redistributables to get Windows SDK to install correctly. That turned out to be true. I deleted all my MSCV 9 (2008) and MSCV 10 (2010) redistributables. I successfully installed Windows SDK and did my compile. Soon I noticed my computer was behaving strangely. Some things were running at normal speed, some were running slowly. One older program (perhaps built with Visual Studio 2008?) in particular was running much more slowly than normal.

I see here a question about getting back the redistributables that you need: [Unistalled C++ Redistributables on Windows Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/576113/unistalled-c-redistributables-on-windows-vista)

What I'm confused about is why, if my problem was that certain needed redistributable DLLs were deleted, certain program would run slower, instead of not running at all as in the question just cited.

Is there some kind of "fallback" process going on where if it can't find the right redistributable it can fall back to a slower alternative? Possibly it's finding a debug redistributable somewhere on my machine?

I see in [Unistalled C++ Redistributables on Windows Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/576113/unistalled-c-redistributables-on-windows-vista) how to find a *missing* redistributable. But is there an easy way for me to see which alternative dlls might be loading up? Perhaps I can use procmon to watch what gets opened...

More background: Here are the links that led me to uninstall the redistributables:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366006/error-when-installing-windows-sdk-7-1

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c8f8fcf-959e-4daf-b7b1-2c64d173e10d/microsoft-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-and-net-framework-4-fails-to-install?forum=vssetup